# Run simple word count program using Apache Spark with python

Tags: python, centos7

I have created a Apache Spark cluster (using pre-build for Hadoop distribution) having three machines, two are working as a compute node and one is working as master and compute node. I have installed all required software like Apache Hadoop, JAVA 8, Scala.

Now I want to run a simple word count program on my cluster. I copied program available at  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py and saved it in a spark_wc.py.

I am running this script with argument as a file name which is already stored on Hadoop HDFS, it is giving error as

```
python spark_wc.py file.txt
2018-09-10 12:12:56 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "spark_wc.py", line 19, in <module>
lines = spark.read.text(sys.argv[1]).rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 328, in text
return self._df(self._jreader.text(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(paths)))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
 pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/ncra/file.txt;'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve]. Do not post error messages (or code) as images.

Comment: You were asked two days ago to replace that screen shot with the actual text of the error. The help center is really clear about the fact that people should be available after asking questions, to react to feedback.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import Row

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
RddDataSet = sc.textFile("word_count.dat");
words = RddDataSet.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" "))
result = words.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
result = result.collect()
for word in result:
    print("%s: %s" %(word[0], word[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the error it seems the path is not present.

I suspect you have kept your file in local file system. If so try appending the path like below

file:/yourpath/filename.csv